# Программа для записи в файл значений без перезаписи

Tags: java

В связи с тем, что я только учусь, хочу реализовать примерно такую программу, объясните как реализовать.

1. Запускаем файл, открывается консоль
2. Сообщение в консоли "Какие траты были сегодня ?"
3. Пишем например "Авто"
4. После введения названия траты отображается сообщение "Сколько потратили ?"
5. После ввода суммы нажимаем ввод.
6. Надпись: "Запись успешно произведена, хотите дополнить"
7. Если ввести "Да", то производится новая запись, начинается с пункта 2
8. Если ввести "Нет", то программа закрывается.

Необходимо реализовать запись введенных данных в файл в виде таблицы в формате 1. Значение   сумма (и возможно дата) не перезаписывая содержимое файла

Comment: *Значение сумма (и возможно дата) не перезаписывая содержимое файла* FOR APPEND

Comment: А вы не думали использовать для этих целей файловую базу данных с простым подключением по jdbc?